# Change the ip of GWT application server from 12.0.1.1

Tags: java, gwt, jetty

When i start the development mode server in GWT, i get the following url

```
http://localhost:8080/myproject/show/mainpage?gwt.codesvr=127.0.1.1:9997
```

If i understand correctly, Jetty is running on port 8080 of localhost and my applications server is running on ip 127.0.1.1 and port 9997.

Is there a way to make the code server too listen on port 9997 of localhost or 127.0.0.1 insstead of 127.0.1.1 ?

Thank You

Comment: Hum, not sure what you mean. By default it listens on 127.0.0.1. Did you mistyped something? Or else, could you tell us how you launch your application server.

Comment: I launch it by running ./run-client on my Ubuntu machine

Comment: From wiki: "The most commonly used IP address on the loopback device is 127.0.0.1 for IPv4, although any address in the range 127.0.0.0 to 127.255.255.255 is mapped to it". GWT development mode browser plugin is already listening to localhost for GWT development mode server.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9386791/how-to-see-gwt-jetty-devmode-from-another-machine/9600986#9600986

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what the run-client script does. 
Usually development mode is starting via `ant devmode` or directly in eclipse. 
If you use `ant` you can modify the build.xml file to change some parameters. 
In case of eclipse you can change the port and ip in debug/run configuration.

For for more details on configuration parameters in dev-mode, e.g.:

```
-port
-bindAddress
```

see [here](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging.html#What_options_can_be_passed_to_development_mode).