# How to see GWT Jetty devmode from another machine?

Tags: java, gwt, jetty

When I fire up Jetty, it gives me the standard URL: http://127.0.0.1:8888/index.jsp?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997

Great. I can see this URL from my machine. However, I cannot access this URL from other machine, and replacing the 127.0.0.1 with my actual IP address does not work either.

Does anyone know how I can make my server "sharable" so that other people in my network can hit off my machine as well?

Answer (score 7):

Try to start the server with `-bindAddress` option using your external IP. See [this](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging.html#What_options_can_be_passed_to_development_mode).

Comment: Do you know how to use this in conjunction with "ant devmode"? ant devmode -bindAddress is not valid.

Comment: you will probably need to alter `build.xml`. Inside you can specify some variable to pass as this param: `-bindAddress ${bindAddress}`. Then in command line you do `-DbindAddress=<your IP>`. In fact, it may already be there just check for the proper variable name.

Answer (score 3):

Just follow the following Steps,

1. Right Click on Project
2. Go to run as ---- > Run Configurations
3. Select Arguments and add **-bindAddress 0.0.0.0** to Program Arguments
4. Click On Apply & Run